# MacOS terminal cp does not do anything and shows usage instruction

Tags: operating-system

I am running this from my terminal:

```
cp build/*.js /Users/amin/servers/tomcat/work/static/vaadin/
```

But the command just shows me usage instructions, and does not copy the files:

```
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file ... target_directory
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me once, and my problem was that the directory I was copying to, didn't exist. Does yours?